# Unity: transform.GetComponent Vs. GameObject.GetComponent?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering what the difference was between the transform and gameobject getcomponents.

I looked at this resource here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1360282/what-is-the-difference-between-gameobjectgetcompon.html

It states that: "At the end, both are the same"

Surely there must be a difference between the two?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are equivalent.

Keep in mind Unity's component-based architecture: almost everything that exists in the scene is a GameObject which usually has one or more Components attached to it. A Component *must* be attached to a GameObject in order to exist.

The `GetComponent` method, really an entire family of methods, allows scripts to look up references to specific Components.

If you call `GetComponent` on a GameObject (such as `gameObject.GetComponent`), it will find a matching Component attached to that GameObject.

If you call `GetComponent` on a Component (such as `transform.GetComponent`), it will find the GameObject that component is attached to, then find a matching Component attached to that GameObject. This is the same result, but it's a convenient shorthand to save you the effort of putting `gameObject` references all over your scripts.

Technically these are separate methods, but the results and semantics are essentially identical. In practice you can use whichever form you are more comfortable with.

Comment: I see. That clarifies a lot of things. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Surely there must be a difference between the two?

There isn't. They both call the same method in the same object. Actually, transform.GetComponent has one more level of indirection (difference in performance won't be noticeable tbh).

`gameObject.GetComponent` looks more clean and logical, if you already have a direct reference to the GO.